# Filtering postgres data using bytea column

Tags: java, postgresql, barcode, bytea

I have a java application that inserts stock items as they are received from the supplier. I capture the bar-code image of the the product along with other information(name,price & so on..). I'm saving the bar-code image inform of bytea in PostgreSQL database. Since I do not yet have a bar-code scanner, I'm taking a photo of the bar-code image and inserting as follows.

```
  //code extract
    File imgFile = new File(barcodeImage.jpg);
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(imgFile);
    pstmt2.setBinaryStream(19, fin,  (int) imgFile.length());  //inserts      into barcodeImage - bytea column
```

I now want to retrive the product from the database using the barcode image i had saved. something like :

```
         select * from stock_item where barcodeImage=***
```

How do I go about to filter the data using the barcodeImage(bytea) column? Just like how the barcode scanners work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way is to scan the bar-code image and store the code as varchar. IMHO

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possibility of different stock items from different suppliers to have same code since that would cause conflict?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, although rarely. The same code may be re-used by another supplier for a new product, because the original product is no longer manufactured.

Comment: Okay, that is manageable then. I had assumed that the output of a bar code scanner is an image. But based on your recommendation, it seems the output is a string of characters. Not so?

Comment: Yes, a string of characters representing the scanned barcode itself (EAN XY, Code XY etc). First, scan the image using [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/) (as suggested by Craig) and store the result as a string of characters to make it queryable.

Comment: Personally, I would not call any possibly long-standing external processes on SQL server. Even if everything goes well, it could unnecessarily prolong the life of the DB transaction and increase the risk of record-locking problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this in the database, you'd need a library that could decode barcodes from raster images (PNG, JPEG, etc), and you'd need to expose that as a PostgreSQL function via a procedural language (PL/Python, PL/Perl, C, etc).

Personally I recommend *not* doing this in the DB. Hand the work out to a pool of external helper processes, each of which analyses a block of codes and updates the DB with the code (if any) found in the image. This gives you more choice of language, isolates the database from any crashes in the barcode decoding software, etc.

My first search found [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/), a Java library for barcode decoding. So I'd probably use that with PgJDBC to produce a simple worker process that fetched a barcode image, decoded it, and updated the row with the decoded barcode. If for some reason I really had to do this in the DB I'd either use PL/Java (warning, here be dragons) or find a barcode decoding library for a better supported in-database language.

Trying to do it like you describe, in the `WHERE` clause, will be utterly hopeless. You'd have to decode the barcode for every image in every query. Completely unmanagable. A functional index would work, but would be hugely expensive to create and a nightmare to maintain in the face of updates to the barcode lib, etc. You need to preprocess this.